# Edit Rejection: "Edit does not address the fundamental issues"

Tags: discussion, edits, review, suggested-edits

When should the edit rejection option, "Edit does not address the fundamental issues." be used?  I hadn't seen this one before, and it was used on [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2475487).  I think that this case was an improper use of it, but I can't find any clarification elsewhere on the site defining when this should be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reviewers can enter a free-form reason when they reject an edit, and that's what happened here. This allows reviewers to provide more specific guidance than the predefined reasons.

In this case, I don't see how the reason is more informative that using the predefined “too minor” reason would be.

I would have accepted this edit. Regardless of whether it addresses *all* the issues, this edit addresses at least two major issues: it formats the code, and makes the text comprehensible at first glance.

Comment: Maybe denoting that an edit rejection comment was custom would be helpful.